# Override Tabulator Page number with localization/langs data

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Based on the provided documents/examples found here:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/localize

I have found no way to actually override the localization applied when hovering over the table page numbers themselves. So even in the example provided at the above link, if you set the table to German, and then hover over the 1 or 2 page number, you will see "Show Page 1" written in English. I haven't been able to find the name of the property I can use to override this.

Comment: In order to override the Show Page tooltip, you need to enter in the following inside the langs , pagination object: "page_title": "my new title"

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the Show Page tooltip, you need to enter in the following inside the langs , pagination object: "page_title": "my new title"

for example:

```
  locale: "es-es",
  langs: {
    "es-es": {
      "pagination": {
        "page_title": "Mostrar página"
      }
    }
  }
```